# display the users order history (laravel)

Tags: laravel

I want to create a page that shows users what they bought but I really have no idea how can I do this!
and this is cart view and I don't have cart model:

```
public  function  addtocart(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        if (empty($data['user_email'])){
            $data['user_email'] = ' ';
        }

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
        if (empty($session_id)){
            $session_id = Str::random(40);
            Session::put('session_id' , $session_id);
        }

        DB::table('cart')->insert(['product_id' => $data['product_id'] ,  'product_name' => $data['product_name'], 'user_id'=>$user_id,
            'product_price' => $data['product_price'], 'qty' => $data['qty'], 'user_email' => $data['user_email'] , 'session_id' => $session_id ]);

        return redirect('cart');
    }
```

```
 public function cart(){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
        $userCart = DB::table('cart')->where(['session_id'=>$session_id])->get();
        foreach ( $userCart as $key=>$product){
            $productDetail = Singleproduct::where('id' , $product->product_id)->first();
            $userCart[$key]->image = $productDetail->image;
        }
        return view('UI.store.cart' , compact('userCart'));
    }
```

can anyone help me in it plz?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of orders for a user you can do:

```php
$history = DB::table('cart')
       ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
       ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'cart.product_id')
       ->select('products.name', 'cart.quantity', 'cart.product_price')
       ->get();
```

Then it's up to you to output it how you want

Comment: I got database error!"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '***. singleproducts' doesn't exist (SQL: select `singleproducts`.`name`, `cart`.`quantity`, `cart`.`product_price` from `cart` inner join ` singleproducts` on `products`.`id` = `cart`.`product_id` where `user_id` is null) " why?!

Comment: It's telling you the problem. THe table doesn't exist. Are you sure your products table is named as such?

Comment: You're using 2 different aliases still. You're using singleproducts.name but then you're joining on products.id where it should be singleproducts...

Comment: $history = DB::table('cart')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->join(' singleproducts', 'singleproducts.id', '=', 'cart.product_id')
            ->select('singleproducts.name', 'cart.quantity', 'cart.price')
            ->get(); I did this